# Windows phone 8.1 emulator not loading OS

Tags: windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8-emulator

I am trying to launch the emulator (Emulator 8.1 WVGA 4 inch 512 MB, or any other as a matter of fact) but it fails to launch.

It goes to the "Loading OS" screen then throws an error box with the text "DEP6100". On VS, it says at the bottom

```
Error1 Error : DEP6100 : The following unexpected error occurred during bootstrapping stage 'Connecting to the device': ObjectDisposedException - 0x80131622
```

and

```
Error2 Error : DEP6100 : The following unexpected error occurred during bootstrapping stage 'Connecting to the device': ObjectDisposedException - 0x80131622
```

Looked in the internet but haven't found an answer yet. Can you please help?

Please let me know what additional information you need.

Comment: are you facing this problem normally or after the Update of Visual Studio Have you updated visual studio ? check if you are having any remaining extension update for your visual studio 2013

Comment: Hi, thanks for looking through. I had VS2013 (update 1) earlier and on that the emulator worked just fine. I had to format my machine due to some corrupt OS file, and when I installed VS2013 with update 2, this began. After I write the code and build it, there is no error. When I debug it, the emulator launches, but after a really long time, throws an error that reads "Error : DEP6100". Thanks again..

Comment: Coreinfo: <pre> Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-1650 0 @ 3.20GHz
Intel64 Family 6 Model 45 Stepping 7, GenuineIntel
HYPERVISOR      *       Hypervisor is present
VMX             -       Supports Intel hardware-assisted virtualization
EPT             -       Supports Intel extended page tables (SLAT) </pre>

Comment: I have the same issue, but with a Lumia 930 device.

Comment: You should look at this article it helped me out! http://daxdude.blogspot.com/2015/01/error-dep6100-bootstrapping-0x80131622.html basically make sure that your vEthernet for Windows Phone in network connections is enable!

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem on a fresh install of Windows 8.1 and Visual Studio 2013 Update 3.

Firstly, I went through all of the Microsoft requirements and suggested steps for problems found on MSDN here:
[Windows Phone Emulator for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff402563(v=vs.105).aspx)

After confirming that I met the requirements and none of the possible fix suggestions fixed my problem, I tried the following, which fixed the errors I was getting with the emulator.

I fixed the problem by:

- Closing Visual Studio
- Going to the "Control Panel"
- Selecting "Programs and Features"
- Find "Windows Phone 8.1 Emulators - ENU" in the list
- Click the "Change" button at the top or right-click and select "Change"
- On the "Visual Studio" window that appears; select "Repair"
- Wait for the process to complete, and re-open Visual Studio
- Run the emulator again and it works this time!

You may have to restart your PC if you left Visual Studio open in order for the changes to take effect. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem . first i fixed it with:

- Updating windows
- Uninstall / install Windows Phone SDK 8
- Remove and add Hyper-v again ( maybe it is not necessary )

But problem came back and instead of previous solution i fixed the issue with :

- going to windows firewall and then click on "restore defaults"

Answer (score 1):

Installing McAfee seemed to block out my emulator... I uninstalled it and restored default firewall settings and it's working for now...

Comment: This is probably my issue.  Unfortunately, I can't un-install McAfee from my work computer.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your processor supports the necessary requirements for running the emulators.  After a few hours of trying I finally checked on...and the processor I have doesn't support at least one of the requirements.

Run `coreinfo -v` - available [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/cc835722) - you're looking for an `*` next to EPT (on Intel) or NPT (on AMD).  If it shows a `-` then you need a different processor.  Good luck!

Comment: So if I get a - next to VMX and EPT there's no way to turn it on in the BIOS or anything?

Answer (score 0):

For Windows 10 Emulators 10.0.1.0 (1081p 2gb)

You should Delete all (VHD and AVHD) files in:
C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\XDE\10.0.1.0\

All will be recreated when the emulator wil restart. Replace MyUserName by you user name.
Should work for other emulator.
See you :)

Answer (score 0):

I had your same problem and after many attempts resolved it this way:

1. Deactivate Hyper-V (and restart computer);
2. Go in the Device Manager and open the Network Adapters, here uninstall *everything* with the name "Hyper-V...", this will allow us to reactivate Hyper-V without any conflict;
3. Enable Hyper-V (and restart computer);

Finally launch the emulator (if it is the first time you launch it you will have to wait 5-10 minutes, so be patient and wait for it to load all apps it need).