# Windows App Deployment Failure to Lumia phone

Tags: windows-phone, visual-studio-2015

I'm currently working on a Universal 8.1 app.
I've always deployed it for testing on my Lumia 535 without any problem. However, today I'm unable to deploy. I get this error code.

DEP6200 : Bootstrapping failed. Device cannot be found. 0x89731810: Deployment failed because no Windows Phone was detected. Make sure a phone is connected and powered on.

This problem occurred previously and disappeared when I updated my PC windows from build 10240 to 10586. Then I was using a Lumia 535 for deployment.
Now I'm using a Lumia 640xl and the problem suddenly resurfaced.
I've:
- repaired my visual studio installation
- changed USB cable
- tried the proposed solutions in the below links (except reverting to Win 8.1 or factory reset).

Still the problem persists.

I've tried all the solutions from these links [Windows phone 8.1 emulator not loading OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24061437/windows-phone-8-1-emulator-not-loading-os)

[Error : DEP6200 : Bootstrapping 'Device' failed. Device cannot be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33652885/error-dep6200-bootstrapping-device-failed-device-cannot-be-found)

[Tools for Apache Cordova DEP6200 Windows Universal App Windows Phone Won't Connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36558671/tools-for-apache-cordova-dep6200-windows-universal-app-windows-phone-wont-cone)

[Fail to run an app developed on desktop (Visual Studio 2015) on usb-connected "Surface 3"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36396637/fail-to-run-an-app-developed-on-desktop-visual-studio-2015-on-usb-connected-s)

[Windows 10 Mobile Error: DEP6200](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33847103/windows-10-mobile-error-dep6200)

Please what can I do?

Comment: Are you trying to uninstall emulators in order to deploy to a real device? That shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: I only tried uninstalling the emulator as a troubleshooting step. I only need to deploy to my real device, not an emulator.

Comment: Is your phone developer unlocked?

Comment: My phone is developer unlocked. I was trying to REdeploy my developed app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem for a long time, but finally found a solution. Plug in your Lumia, go to Device Manager and uninstall it with drivers, then reboot. Everything should work fine. I know, I'm a bit late, but this answer might help someone else;)