# Windows 10 Mobile Error: DEP6200

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-mobile, lumia, windows-10-universal

I am trying to deploy a Windows 10 app to a Lumia 635 running 10.0.10586.11 and I get this error:

> Error : DEP6100 : The following unexpected error occurred during bootstrapping stage 'Connecting to the device 'DEVICE GUID'.': SEHException - External component has thrown an exception.
>
> Error : DEP6200 : Bootstrapping 'Device' failed. Device cannot be found. The data necessary to complete this operation is not yet available.

Unlike most, I am capable of deploying to an Emulator, just not the physical device. Based on this question: [Error : DEP6200 : Bootstrapping 'Device' failed. Device cannot be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33652885/error-dep6200-bootstrapping-device-failed-device-cannot-be-found)

I verified that Windows Phone 8.1 is installed, and ensured that the latest SDK is installed, so neither of those were solutions. I am able to deploy to physical hardware for desktop/tablet mode, but no go on the Lumia 635.

Comment: Is the phone developer unlocked?

Comment: Make sure your phone is registered.

Comment: Yes, the phone is unlocked. As the included link said to try, I undid and reregistered the device to no vail.

Comment: I have a similar issue but...  I was able to deploy to the phone before updating my windows 10 machine with the big win10 update.  I don't know if it is related or not.

Comment: I'm not running the Fall Update on my development machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, it was an issue with the installation of Windows 10 Mobile on my device. After a reset the deployment works great, and I have deployed dozens of apps to the device.

Answer (score 2):

Installing the latest mobile emulator preview fixed the deployment issue for me.

https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/windows-10-developer-preview

Answer (score 0):

1/3 Try registry patch

[How to develop windows 10 uwp on real device (mobile)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33473200/how-to-develop-windows-10-uwp-on-real-device-mobile)

2/3 Update your UWP Tools. Latest one is '1.2', included at VS2015 Update1 RC. It's go-live. (But RTM ver will be released at 30 Nov.)

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-update1-vs.aspx

3/3 This is just a workaround ... you can use "DevicePortal" to deploy your .appx package to your mobile device directly without Visual Studio.
Following blog is written in Japanese but the screenshots may helps you.

http://ddlgjp.blogspot.jp/2015/10/deviceportal-uwp-app-win10-mobile.html