# Debug UWP on Device Windows 10 Mobile?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, uwp, windows-10-mobile

how to debug UWP application on windows 10 Mobile build 10586.11 from Visual Studio 2015?
always error like this :
[image]

How to solve it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to develop windows 10 uwp on real device (mobile)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33473200/how-to-develop-windows-10-uwp-on-real-device-mobile) and [another similar question is here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33847103/2681948).

Comment: I think you will need the emulators for the released version of windows 10 mobile to fix this

Comment: Hi Gigin. Could you provide a bit more information? Specifically:
What version of VS are you using?
What is the latest SDK you have installed?
Does your device have "Device Discovery" enabled?

Answer (score 0):

Hi i also have windows 10 mobile 10586.11 build after doing reset my device is not connected in my PC/Visual Studio 2015.
so please check your device is connected in PC.
then goto--> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.1\Tools\Phone Registration open the PhoneReg tool.

[image: Developer mode is register or unregister]