# Fail to run an app developed on desktop (Visual Studio 2015) on usb-connected "Surface 3"

Tags: visual-studio, windows-10, pixelsense, surface

I want to develop an application in Visual Studio 2015 on my desktop
and run/test it on my Surface 3.

I created a Blank application (Universal Windows) and I can run it on “local machine” but  when trying to run it on “Device” I get the following error

```
Error  DEP6200 : Bootstrapping failed. Device cannot be found. 0x89731810:
Deployment failed because no Windows Phone was detected. 
Make sure a phone is connected and powered on. App1
```

Both are running Windows 10 version 1511 (Build 10586.164).
The surface is connected with USB. 
The developer mode on the Surface 3 is activated.
IpOverUsbSvc is running on the desktop.

Note that I don’t seem to find the Surface 3 in the Device Manager
and when I plug it in, no attempt seems to be made to install drivers.
This is probably the root cause so any advice to let "Device Manager" recognize the "Surface 3" would be appreciated

Comment: Device is reserved for Windows Phone and Windows 10 Mobile devices - PCs or other devices need to be used with Remote Debugging tools I think it's Remote Device in options - not 100% certain hence this is a comment not an answer but hopefully will help

Comment: @RoguePlanetoid This indeed did the trick so feel free to convert it to an answer. Note that it's called "Remote Machine" and that I had to install msvsmon.exe on the Surface (included in "remote tools for visual studio 2015"). This link also proved very helpful to me https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh441469.aspx.   One final question though: how can I know whether a device is a "Windows 10 mobile device" or a PC? Suppose I want to buy a "windows 10 mobile" tablet, how can I avoid buying a PC?

Comment: Windows 10 Mobile devices tend only to be the phones at the moment so should be easy to make sure you get right device e.g. Lumia 950 but there are more cheaper devices available coming from a variety of companies so can pick one that suits you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To debug on a remote device such as a Surface 3, you need to install the Remote Debugging tools for Visual Studio 2015 then select the "Remote Machine" option, the "Device" option is reserved for Windows Phone and Windows 10 Mobile devices at the moment