# Tools for Apache Cordova DEP6200 Windows Universal App Windows Phone Won't Connect

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-phone, visual-studio-cordova

I receive the following error when trying to connect to a Nokia 925 running windows 10.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       DEP6200 : Bootstrapping failed. Device cannot be found. 0x89731810: Deployment failed because no Windows Phone was detected. Make sure a phone is connected and powered on.
```

I can't get the phone to connect.  The phone syncs pictures and charges fine.

I am running Windows 10 on my laptop.   I have developer features enabled on my windows 10 and my phone.  I can pair my phone to the pc using the device portal on the phone.

I am running Visual Studio Enterprise 2015

I am reviewing options posted to a similar question here:
[Windows 10 Mobile Error: DEP6200](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33847103/windows-10-mobile-error-dep6200)

I reset the device to factory settings removing all applications and the problem persists.

I have made sure the make sure "Windows Phone IP over USB Transport (IpOverUsbSvc)" service is running.

As a temporary work around, I am compiling my application for ARM and uploading it to the device via the device portal manually.   This at least allows me to manually test on the device even though it is not a true development environment.

Comment: Ctrl+R to open Run window and type services.msc . Make sure "Windows Phone IP over USB Transport (IpOverUsbSvc)" service is running.

Comment: Thanks Alan, I have done that and manually restarted the service also.

Comment: This is a long shot...but, I've seen this issue when accidentally using a USB cable to connect my phone and that cable was only designed for charging. Maybe try another cable?